# Rich snippet errors in Google's Structured Data Testing Tool for category pages

Tags: rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets-tool

I'm receiving the following errors in Google's Structured Data Testing Tool:

[image: Rich Snnipets Tools Errors]

It seems like the page for the category "galeria" does not contain these fields. There are also some more errors like this (all with categories links). The strange thing is that the first category doesn't show those errors.

Anyway, I added the "entry-title" fields:

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="page-title pad group">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>Categoría <span>Biología</span></h1>
    </div>
    ...
</section>
```

but the error is still there.

Also, "author" and "update" doesn't seem to make sense here (categories), so should those messages be ignored?

**Update:**

[Here](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbiologiainteresante.com) is a link to Google's Structured Data Testing Tool for the page to demonstrate this, and to view the HTML code by clicking on the HTML tab.

Comment: I spent a little time on schema.org trying to figure this question out and unless I have totally missed something, I cannot figure this out. Can you supply an anonymous rich snippet code sample of what is failing including any nesting?

Comment: Please add a section of your rich snippet code containing the issue, or a link to [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) containing your HTML code, so that others can view what the issue might be and learn from it.

Comment: Is this a Wordpress site/plugin by chance?

Comment: @dan - I've added a link to Google's Structured Data Testing Tool.

Comment: @closetnoc - I've added a link to Google's Structured Data Testing Tool.

Comment: @user1795832 - Yes, it is.

Comment: @Manolo Thanks, I clarified the question a bit more for you too.

Comment: @Manolo What wordpress themes and/or plugins are you using?

Comment: @Manolo Looking at your HTML there on your page, you have articles within articles, no "updated" class name, and no author vcard classes anywhere on that page.  I'm guessing whatever plugin you are using took you down the wrong path, but your structured data needs to look like this:  http://microformats.org/wiki/hatom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors were not due to the categories or tag pages, but to the slider and the sidebar posts in home page. So to solve it I just had to add rich snippets to all the posts shown there (also in categories and tags pages).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to make sure that the `hentry` class appears on a tag which appears **outside** of all the other fields, so that the other microformat classes are child elements to it.

On your category pages, you are putting `class="entry-title"` in an area that is not nested within the `article` tag which has the `hentry` class.

Try adding `class="hentry"` to your `body` tag instead, so that all your microformat tags appear within it.

Comment: I've tried, but get the same result.